# ASCII коды в ReadKey

Tags: pascal

Доброго времени суток!

Функция keypressed говорит true, если у нас в буфер попал символ. Насколько я знаю, некоторые клавиши используют два байта. Всегда ли первый байт 0, если есть второй? (Если не всегда, то пример приведите, пожалуйста.) Существуют ли расширенные коды, состоящие больше чем из двух байтов? (Тоже примерчик...) И если всё-таки есть больше, чем из двух, то как определить сколько их там накопилось?
(ОС Windows)

Спасибо!

Comment: не могу ответить на все вопросы, но, например, Enter в Windows это два символа `#10` `#13`, и `readkey` возвращает `#13`.

Comment: Это знаем... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [таблице кодов](http://pascal.toom.su/ReadKey) виртуальных клавиш:

1. первый байт всегда 0, если есть второй,
2. расширенных кодов больше, чем на два байта нет.

Что также следует и из описания функции [ReadKey](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/readkey.html)

> ReadKey читает 1 код из буфера клавиатуры и возвращает его. Если расширенная или функциональная клавиша была нажата, то нулевое значение ASCII кода возвращается. Прочитать скан-код клавиши можно со второго вызова ReadKey.